# Passing multiple data parameters from $.ajax to webmethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am trying to pass some data parameters from ajax call for webmethod. but it doesn't pass them to the webmethod. following is the code

```
function databind(query,tbl,para,spname,cmdtype){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "editviewposition.aspx/threeDTable",
            data: "{query':'"+query+"','tbl':'"+tbl+"','para':'"+para+"','spname':'"+spname+"','cmdtype':'"+cmdtype+"'}",  // here is the problem
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
     }
```

webmethod

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function threeDTable(ByVal query As String, ByVal tbl As String, ByVal para() As Object, ByVal spname As String, ByVal cmdtype As String) As Object()()()
        'code
    End Function
```

Comment: I would prefer `data: JSON.stringify({query:query,tbl:tbl,para:para,spname:spname,cmdtype:cmdtype})` rather than string concatenation. Problem with your version is that you missed quotes before in snippet `{ query`

Comment: thanks.give it as solution. i will mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your version is that you missed quotes before *query* in snippet `data: "{query':'`

However I would recommend you to use [**JSON.stringify()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a value to JSON, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

*Code Example*

```
data: JSON.stringify({query:query,tbl:tbl,para:para,spname:spname,cmdtype:cmdtype})
```